# MSBuild parse item metadata

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.0, msdeploy

Is there anyway to modify each item in an item group?  For example, given this item:

```
<_CustomAreas Include="..\My.Project.*\Areas\**\*.*" Condition="'$(AppBuildFolder)' == ''" />
```

I want to remove the "..\My.Product.* portion.  Basically we have separate project containing MVC areas, and in the Package / Deployment (MSDeploy) we want to copy them into the main project.  Here's where the group is used:

```
<FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomAreas.Identity)">
    <DestinationRelativePath>Areas\%(relativedir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
</FilesForPackagingFromProject>
```

`$(relativedir)` is coming through as "..\My.Project.Plugin1\Areas***.*" and it ends up in the package as `ZipFileRoot\My.Project.Plugin1\Areas`  (The .. backs out of the hardcoded Areas, and then it just creates the folder for the plugin\areas) where I'd like it to actually all end up in `ZipFileRoot\Areas`.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RegexReplace](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/svn/msbuildtasks/trunk/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Regex/RegexReplace.cs) (credentials: guest/guest) task should be able to match `\My.Product.*` and replace with an empty string.

Something like this should work: (untested, need to verify escaping)

```
<RegexReplace Input="%(_CustomAreas)" Expression="\\My\.Product\..*" Replacement="" Count="-1">
    <Output ItemName="_CustomAreas" TaskParameter="Output" />
</RegexReplace>
```

There's a little work getting the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) up and running, but enough good stuff in there for me to find it worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

With MsBuild 4.0 You can use String methods directly in your script (or use inline tasks). With this option, you can edit your relativedir to delete the My.Project.* part .

You can see examples in this article : http://sedodream.com/2010/03/07/MSBuild40PropertyFunctionsPart1.aspx

Comment: I like this answer as well, but it wasn't clear to me how to operate on an ItemGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Items in ItemGroups can have an Exclude attribute that allows you to specify items to leave out.

Comment: That's not what I was asking to do.